# Subtract month from varchar year and date parameter format '2016-11'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I have a table that has columns reportyear and reportmonth. For reportyear, the column is a vharchar (4) that equals to year 2016 format. For reportmonth, it is a varchar (2) that has a 01, 02, 03, etc. format. I have a data parameter that concatenates the two since our end users want a drop down date. So my parameter is @ReportDate varchar (7).

My problem is for one of my selects in my stored procedure, I need to put a where clause where it goes back a month. So if my parameter equals to '2016-11', I want a where clause where it returns '2016-10'. I have successfully done this using the flowing query:

```
SUBSTRING(@Reportdate, 1, 4) + '-' + cast(substring(@ReportDate, 6, 7)  -1 as varchar(20))
```

This returns '2016-10' if I pick '2016-11' as any report date parameter.
But upon further thinking, this would not work if my report date is in January because the above query just literally subtract a string value. So if I pick '2016-01', the above query would return '2016-0'.

Answer (score 0):

**For Example:**

```
Declare @Reportdate varchar(7) = '2016-01'

Select AsDate  = dateadd(MM,-1,@ReportDate+'-01')
      ,AsSting = left(convert(date,dateadd(MM,-1,@ReportDate+'-01'),101),7)
```

Returns

```
AsDate      AsSting
2015-12-01  2015-12
```

Comment: End users want the drop down parameter in SSRS to be with dashes that is why I declared it as varchar(7) to include the dash @John Cappelletti

Comment: @Lisbon I updated to include the dash when I saw the comment.  The varchar(7) vs varchar(10) is non-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `case`:

```
select concat(@ReportYear - 1,
              (case when @ReportMonth = '01' then '12'
                    else right(concat('0', @ReportMonth - 1))
               end)
             )
```

SQL Server will treat the strings as ints -- with no conversion errors for your values.  `concat()` then converts them back into strings.

EDIT:

I see, this is backwards.  Let's add one to the columns in the table and compare to `@Report_Month`:

```
where (reportmonth = 12 and
       right(@ReportDate, 2) = '01' and left(@Report_date, 4) = reportyear + 1
      ) or
      (left(@ReportDate, 4) = reportyear and
       right(@ReportDate, 2) = reportmonth + 1
      )
```

But after considering this, I think you should use a computed column:

```
alter table t add reportdate as ( datefromparts(reportyear, reportmonth, 1) );
```

Then simply do:

```
where dateadd(month, 1, reportdate) = cast(@reportdate + '01' as date)
```

Of course, you can do the explicit comparison:

```
where (dateadd(month, 1, datefromparts(reportyear, reportmonth, 1)) =
       cast(@reportdate + '01' as date)
      )
```

Note that both of these assume that `@reportdate` is a string.

Comment: My parameter is atReportDate which is a concatenation of Reportyear and reportmonth column. So in my where clause, I have it as:

where reportyear + '-' + reportmonth = @ReportDate (ReportDate being '2016-11')